# How to create a directory using nerdtree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I have been using NERDTree for a while. Every time I need to create a new directory I need to go to terminal. Is there a quick and easy way to create a directory using NERDTree.

I read the [doc](http://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/raw/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt) but could not find anything.

Comment: This might belong in Super User.

Comment: I wouldn't move it to Super User.  Sysadmins use Vim, but developers who use Vim live in it all day; I'd venture it's more applicable to devs.  If there were a way to link/clone it, that'd be a good choice.

Comment: The relevant lines in the doc is very inconspicuous. It is in the 'NERDTreeMenu' [section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459750/vim-and-nerd-tree-extension-adding-a-file).

Answer (score 264, accepted):

When in the NERDTree window, press 'm'; you should see a menu at the bottom. Type in 'a' for add childnode. Now input the directory you want to create, making sure to add a '/' at the end, otherwise the script would create a file.

AFAIK NERDTree cannot create parent directories like 'mkdir -p' does.

Comment: when type a I get an error Error detected while processing function <SNR>_15_showMenu..... . Culprit could be some other plugin. I will debug it later. thanks.

Comment: i use mkdir but nodetree filesystem structire does not refresh automatically

Comment: What's more ,you should put the nerdtree_plugin dir(which is in your download package) into the .vim dir ,or when you press 'm' there would be an error happen. Thanks for Housetier's answer

Comment: @nkint you should go back to nerdtree, and press R

Comment: Now NERDTree can create parent directories.

Answer (score 17):

Pressing `m` would open a menu below and you can select from a list of actions.

```
NERDTree Menu. Use j/k/enter and the shortcuts indicated
==========================================================
> (a)dd a childnode
  (m)ove the current node
  (d)elete the current node
  (r)eveal in Finder the current node
  (o)pen the current node with system editor
  (q)uicklook the current node
  (c)opy the current node
Add a childnode
==========================================================
Enter the dir/file name to be created. Dirs end with a '/'
/Library/WebServer/Documents/new-teacher-center/app/Model/
```

Pressing `a` would let you add a childnode. A childnode can be a file or folder depending if you add a forward slash ( / ) or not.

If you don’t add a forward slash like below, it would create a file.

```
Add a childnode
==========================================================
Enter the dir/file name to be created. Dirs end with a '/'
/Library/WebServer/Documents/new-project/app/Model/file
```

If you add a forward slash like below, it would create a folder.

```
Add a childnode
==========================================================
Enter the dir/file name to be created. Dirs end with a '/'
/Library/WebServer/Documents/new-project/app/Model/folder/
```

Comment: This is the correct, more up-to-date answer. Its not a very well, or very obvious option in the menu, but this handles it.  Otherwise `:!mkdir -p path/to/dest`.