# Prevent "modifiable is off" in vim

Tags: vim

How can I prevent VIM to set modifiable to off?

I have many files opened in VIM and when I want to navigate to a directory I use `:E`. Sometimes (I cannot reproduce when) VIM sets `modifiable` to off. When I go back to my file, I cannot make changes until I run `:set modifiable`.

I want modifiable to be on always. How can I do this?

Seems that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5745506/1420197) doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: I would suggest don't "automatically set it always on", instead, you could create a shortcut (mapping), e.g. `<leader>m` to `:set ma`. in this way, you know which buffer you want to do force modification. it could avoid some dangerous changes in some case.

Comment: @Kent But... it's so annoying to run always `:set ma` and then `:w!` (because readonly turns on also)... Isn't any safe solution?

Comment: I'm using nerdtree facing the same problem.

Comment: @laike9m I use nertree, also - but I don't think that that's the problem. My problem was fixed after [this change in `.vimrc` file](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/configs/commit/9e2aebde73b8e70d39dc20f79df74968e29a02c1).

Comment: So now you can add file using nerdtree without typing `:set ma`? I don't see how you did it in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: @laike9m I didn't have problems with nerdtree. I guess it was because of one of the `.vimrc` functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem lies in the *sometimes (I cannot reproduce when)*. Vim doesn't set this on its own, it's probably a plugin or other part of your configuration that runs amiss. Next time this happens, find out where this got set via

```
:verbose setlocal modifiable?
```

Once the root cause is known, you can do something about it.

If everything fails, and you also cannot / do not want to (temporarily, for testing) shut down plugins and configuration, the "big hammer" method would be an autocmd like this, which attempts to always turn off the option:

```
:autocmd BufWinEnter * setlocal modifiable
```

Comment: Yes.. I have some installed plugins. How can I know which one produces the problem? [This is my .vimrc](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/configs/blob/master/vim-files/.vimrc)

Comment: @Johnツ The `:verbose` may already tell you if you're lucky. Otherwise, binary search is an alternative: Disable half of your plugins and see whether the problem's gone.

Comment: I don't think binary search is a good solution here. Maybe it is the only one, but considering the problem happens randomly, you'd need to spend days working without half of your plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I found that MacVim would always open new files with modifiable off after upgrading my Mac to Leopard.  In my case a newer version of NERDTree fixed it for me.  I installed NERDTree with pathogen, so a `git pull` from `~/.vim/bundle/NERDTree` did the trick.

Comment: Just in case it helps someone else, I found I could turn off the **non modifiable** notice by changing the line that says `setlocal nonmodifiable ` to `setlocal modifiable ` in `~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/ui.vim`